# v-calendar different dates on manual input and selecting from popover

Tags: vue.js, timezone, vcalendar

I have datepicker with current setup:

```
<v-date-picker
    v-model="startDate"
    :min-date='minDate'
    :max-date='maxDate'
    :popover="{ visibility: 'click' }"
>
   <template v-slot="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
         <input
            class="form-control form-control-sm"
            :value="inputValue"
            v-on="inputEvents"
   />
   </template>
</v-date-picker>
```

I set inital date (startDate) as: **2020-07-08T00:00:00.000Z**.
If i change date through datepicker popover, it always stays in the form of beginning of the day ("date"T00:00:00.000Z"). Problem is if I enter date manualy in input field, for example: "2020-07-08", date to which this input is translated is: **2020-07-07T22:00:00.000Z**. So through "manual input" it translates date according to timezone. How can avoid that? how can i get beginning of the day for date i entered manualy?

Thing is, i have records stored in DB with timestamps, and i want to fetch exact records for date range selected through this datepicker component(s)